# Google Maps Integration in IOS

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

So I wanted to view my coordinates of Google Maps on my mobile application (andriod and ios), but unfortunately the coordinates of Google Maps are visible in the Andriods but not in IOS. I am testing Google Maps on Iphone6S tell me if that OK as well. Here is the code:

```
late GoogleMapController _mapController;

final LatLng _center = const LatLng(24.861508799010387, 67.08027442122705);

GoogleMap(
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) =>
                        _mapController = controller,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: _center,
                      zoom: 11.0,
                    ),
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    markers: Set<Marker>.from([
                      Marker(
                        markerId: MarkerId('desired_point'),
                        position: LatLng(24.861508799010387, 67.08027442122705),
                      )
                    ]),
                  ),
```

I have intialized the API Key as well but might be I am a human if you can also tell me the IOS API ket configs as well. Thanks